# Scipy tf2zpk doesn't return zeros

Tags: filters, python, transfer-function, poles-zeros, scipy

I have the following transfer function:

$$H(z) =\frac{\alpha z}{(z-(1-\alpha))}$$

I'd like to find zeros and poles of it by `scipy.signal.tf2zpk`:

```
from scipy.signal import tf2zpk

alpha=0.4
(zeros, poles, gain) = tf2zpk([0, alpha], [1, alpha-1])
```

it is clear that transfer function has zero at `z=0`, but why `tf2zpk` doesn't output it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the documentation yields

> The b and a arrays are interpreted as coefficients for positive, descending powers of the transfer function variable.

You did this correctly for the denominator, but your numerator is turned around in the code. Try

```
(zeros, poles, gain) = tf2zpk([alpha, 0], [1, alpha-1])
```

and it will yield the correct result.

Comment: thank you! I don't have such a keen eye in reading documentations))

Answer (score 1):

If your numerator array is `[0, alpha]` then the numerator polynomial of the corresponding transfer function is $0\cdot z^1+\alpha z^0$, which is not what you intended.